# Express-session store is not returning the full session object with custom data

Tags: node.js, typescript, session, redis, express-session

I've been working on this problem for a while, and I am stumped.

I am using `express-session` with `connect-redis` as a store for the sessions. I am using typescript.

I added this to the top of my server file and I am able to access the fields without any typescript errors.

```
declare module "express-session" {
  interface SessionData {
    userId: string;
    role: UserRole;
  }
}
```

When I log a user in, I set the extra SessionData fields.

```
request.session.userId = user._id.toHexString();
request.session.role = user.role;

console.log(request.session);
```

Via Postman, I can see that the cookie is set and returned. Additionally, I checked Redis for the session key and the session *is* correct. e.g.

```
{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":604800000,\"expires\":\"2023-01-23T17:34:05.158Z\",\"secure\":true,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"userId\":\"1234\",\"role\":\"userRole\"}
```

However, the extra fields I added to SessionData are not being populated after calling the session middleware. Instead of getting:

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-01-23T17:52:49.153Z,
    originalMaxAge: 604800000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true
  },
  userId: '1234',
  role: 'userRole'
}
```

I get:

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-01-23T17:52:52.339Z,
    originalMaxAge: 604800000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true
  }
}
```

This is how I am calling the session middleware:

```
const sessionOptions: SessionOptions = {
  secret: "secret key",
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true, httpOnly: true },
  store: store,
};
app.use(session(sessionOptions));
```

I thought it may have been an issue with redis, but the key/value is being persisted. I thought maybe it was an issue with connect-redis, so I used the default MemoryStore, but that doesn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course right after I ask this question I figure out what the answer is...

First, don't manually set the cookie for the session id in the response. It will automatically be done for you.

Second, ensure that secure is *FALSE* on localhost.

Comment: Can you show your code for example? Thanks!